# how to loop through multiple categories in sigle row using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

i have a database name category

```
 parent_cat      cat_id  title
    0             1      fruit
    0             2      vehicle
    0             3      goods
    1             4      sour
    1             5      sweet
    1             6      mixed
    2             7      sedan
    2             8      hatchback
    2             9      car
```

and i store a object in database table name product

```
obj_name   parent_cat   sub_id

  mango       1          4,5,
  maruti      2          7,8,9
  bmw         2          7,9
```

i want to join the two table to show the data so i need to pass the parameter in URL ie. ?obj=vehicle  i got by doing sql query

```
SELECT category.cat_id,category.title,product.parent_cat,product.obj_name 
    FROM category, product 
    WHERE category.cat_id=product.parent_cat 
AND category.title='$title' --is a difined get variable
```

if title=fruit i got "mango" if title=vehicle i got maruti and bmw
i want to know if title=sedan or title=car then how can i get maruti and bmw
through loop any solution

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: what you tried so far? please add the code you tried till now.

Comment: i have to tables i want to show the obj name according to category title,as category title has single integer so it is wasy to display obj name acc to category title but how can i go through loop for comma separated integer in sub_id to show obj name ie. if URL parameter is title=fruit i got "mango" if title=vehicle i got maruti and bmw i want to know if title=sedan or title=car then how can i get maruti and bmw through loop @Ullas

Comment: title=fruit i got "mango" if title=vehicle i got maruti and bmw  sql query is SELECT category.cat_id,category.title,product.parent_cat,product.obj_name 
    FROM category, product 
    WHERE category.cat_id=product.parent_cat 
AND category.title='$title' --is a difined get variable                                                  <?php
foreach($qry_1 as $v){
 ?>
    <div >
    <p><?php echo $v['obj_name'] ?></p>
    </div>
<?php 
}
?>    @prava

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `LEFT JOIN` query, if you have comma separated values for title use `IN()`

```
SELECT a.cat_id, a.title, b.parent_cat, b.obj_name 
FROM product b 
LEFT JOIN category a
ON a.cat_id = b.parent_cat 
WHERE a.title IN($title);
```

Comment: it returns empty result as how i go through sedan or car if title set to ?title=sedan or ?title=car   as it is comma separated value sub_id @Fabio

Comment: Check updated answer, use `IN()` if you have comma separated values

Comment: according to your code if ?title=vehicle it shows maruti,BMW as it is single int value in field but if  ?title=sedan it returns zero value @Fabio

Comment: This is because you don't have parent_cat with id = 7

Comment: i want to save a obj with parent category and multiple sub category as related to  root and obj in comma separated value so how can i achieve if i want to fetch id from comma separated field @Fabio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT category.cat_id, category.title, product.obj_name, product.parent_cat, product.sub_id FROM category
LEFT JOIN product ON category.cat_id = product.parent_cat OR category.cat_id LIKE '%product.sub_id%'
WHERE category.title LIKE '%$title%'
```

Use `LIKE` instead of `=` when you're not sure of the exact data you're comparing or looking for.

---

**[UPDATE]**

```
SELECT category.cat_id, category.title, product.obj_name, product.parent_cat, product.sub_id FROM product
LEFT JOIN category ON (product.parent_cat = category.cat_id OR product.sub_id LIKE '%category.cat_id%') AND category.title LIKE '%$title%'
```

I'm joining the table in wrong direction, sorry for that.

Comment: i am getting cat id title parent_cat sub_id field having value only 9 ,vehicle only one 1 result and rest is showing null @rhavendc

Comment: i want 9 car maruti  and 9 car bmw @rhavendc

Comment: @priyabratasen Oh, sorry. just view your tables again and I've mistaken joining them. Please try it again, I provided an [UPDATE] query above.

Comment: it shows all the data in the product table i want to know how to process the comma part ,i am stick over their. @rhavendc

Comment: SELECT * FROM products WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',', 9 ,','),CONCAT(',',sub_id,',')) > 0;   @rhavendc          it worked now how can i joined